# Redgate SQL Tools

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am testing the Redgate belt and the set of tools seems pretty amazing... but before I buy anything... could you recommend any other tools similar to these?

Comment: I've used individual tools which are similar to each of the Red Gate tools, but nothing as comprehensive as their whole suite of tools from a single vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only other vendor with a similar line-up and quality that I know of would be [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com)

Comment: I used ApexSQL for a while a couple of years back, trialing it as a DB managment tool against RedGate. Back then my experience was that ApexSQL was a safer tool, you would take a DB backup when using either, but ApexSQL handled things like necessary table drops far more safely. Almost certainly the tools have both evolved, but from my experience ApexSQL is at least worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Database Edition provides a subset of the features RedGate provides.  It might be better than RedGate if your team uses Team Foundation Server for source control.

Comment: Agree, this is what we use at our place. If you're in the BizSpark program, it's all free too. If not, those editions of Visual Studio (Premium and Ultimate) are pretty expensive

Answer (score 1):

If you need data comparison, schema comparison or visual query builder, than you should take a look at our [database tools for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/).